# Using same id names in different xml files in android

Tags: android, xml

Can i use the same id names in in some other layout in a different xml file???
coz i have done dat that and maybe because of that m getting a nullpointer exception and my activity for that xml does not start...

Comment: You can't using same id in different `xml`s.

Comment: Yes he definitely can.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. You can use the same ID's for the same `Widget` type in any number of layouts that you desire. **Just not the same ID in the same Layout XML.** Without getting into the debate whether this is recommended or not of course.

What confuses several developers and I confess, when I started, it did confuse me too. When casting a Widget in the Activity, for example, I was often stumped me why I had just one matching ID when I had the same in a few different layouts.

The only thing you need to take care of is, for example, consider this scenarior:

I have two XML's named, say `layout_1.xml` and `layout_2.xml` and 2 corresponding `Activities`, named say, `Act1` and `Act2`. Now, both have the same `Widget`, say the same `TextView` with the same ID in both XML's. (`Although I am using this example, this is not hypothetical. This is actually how it is in an application of mine`). This is quite contradictory to what *NullPointer* says in his comment. I think he meant you can't use the same ID in the same XML.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFromName"
    style="@style/UserName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="top|left|center"
</TextView>
```

Now, when I am casting this in my code, see what shows up in the suggestions when I start typing the `findViewById(R.id.txtFrom...)`

[image]

Why the **NPE** is perhaps when you use the same ID's in multiple XML files is probably due to some confusion on what the ID is. Keep the corresponding XML open and check the ID when casting and you should be good to go. If it still persists, I would suggest updating your post with your XML code, the Java code and the LogCat crash report.

I keep track of that by literally copying the ID and using the same name as an instance of the Widget when casting it. But, that's just my way I suppose.